# Which class should I use in my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just develoing a Google chrome extension.

I am facing a problem or I'm confusing to get a class to work in my jQuery script.  There are many classes for the textarea.

Someone please tell me which one should I choose.

CSS

```
._5t_y ._4_z2 .input, ._5t_y ._4zz- .input, ._5t_y.child_was_focused ._2yg .input
```

or

HTML

```
class="uiTextareaAutogrow input autofocus _34z- mentionsTextarea textInput"
```

I just trying to add it in to this codes. I tried ".input". But it doesn't work for me.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input').specialedit([':-)', ':-(', ';-)'],
                              { buttonWidth: 30,
                                buttonHeight: 30,
                                toolbarBgColor: '#ff0',
                                toolbarBorderColor: '#f00',
                                buttonBgColor: '#fff',
                                buttonBorderColor: '#f00',
                                buttonTextColor: '#f00' });
  });
```

Comment: Selecting .input is not working? That's not possible problem. .input selects all elements that have input class but obviously it all matters for specificity.

Comment: Or, you need `.uiTextareaAutogrow.input.autofocus._34z-.mentionsTextarea.textInput` ???

Comment: There aren't any standard classes, they're all specific to a particular application or library. So your extension should use the class that's appropriate for it.

Comment: there is something else wrong with your code in the specialedit code , the selector is properly written

Comment: "But it doesn't work for me." - What happens exactly?

Answer (score 3):

If you access it via .input or .uiTextareaAutogrow (knowing that these are the existing classes currently for the same element) you are gonna get your textarea in both cases but the selection set might differ since the elements of class input set might be different than the elements of the class uiTextareaAutogrow set.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the important part of my answer ;)  It's the first time i can vote up my own answer :p

Answer (score 0):

It does not actually differ what class to access, `class` groups HTML elements for a certain reason like formatting or display or any specific business functionality to be applied for this set. So the class selection gets you all the elements having this class.

If you access it via `.input` or `.uiTextareaAutogrow` (knowing that these are the existing classes currently for the same element) you are gonna get your textarea in both cases but the selection set might differ since the elements of class `input` set might be different than the elements of the class `uiTextareaAutogrow` set.

It is a good practice to create a specific class to be used for your plugin to make sure you select what you really need.

For your current case, try to log the selection set `console.log($('.input'))` to make sure the selection is ok and you are getting the element you need, if so you shall check the function you have created to address the problem.